# Is there search query data download function in New Google Webmaster Tool API?

Tags: google-search-console

I'd like to ask about this blog entry:

Deprecation of the old Webmaster Tools API
http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.jp/2015/03/deprecation-of-old-webmaster-tools-api.html

I'd like to use "Python search query data download" function, but according to this blog entry, this function will be discontinued, and replaced by an new API in the upcoming quarters.

I have a question on this. At this moment, should I use the old version or the new version?? I searched api reference pages, I cannot find the new version.

Anyone have an answer on this?